# I need to get every element that I put in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

My purpose is to get, when I'm writing with keyboard, the text. I don' know how event I must use:

```
$('#textarea').on('change',function(){
     console.log( $('#textarea').val() );
});
```

I must modify change with another event.Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `input` event it's very useful to track input fields changes :

```js
$('#textarea').on('input',function(){
     alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='textarea' ></textarea>
```

Hope this helps.

---

Answer (score 1):

Use .`keyup()`

```
$("#textarea").keyup(function(e){        
    console.log($('#textarea').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Any of Key event : `onKeyPress` is occur when any key press,

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function callthis(eventObj){
  lbl=document.getElementById("lbl");
  lbl.value=eventObj.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" onKeyPress="callthis(this)" value="Click me">
    <input type="text" id="lbl"></label>
</body>
</html>
```